# What css is causing this checkbox input to be indented

Tags: css, checkbox, css-float, label

I'd like

```
  [  ] Option 1
  [  ] Option 2
```

but am getting  (http://jsfiddle.net/yN2E8/4/)

```
  [  ] Option 1
       [  ] Option 2
```

What needs to be changed in the CSS to get the boxes left-aligned?  Thanks

Comment: `<div class="labelcontainer">Option 1</div>`?  Looks like a poor attempt at reinventing the wheel.  We have a semantically appropriate tag exactly for this purpose: `<label>Option 1</label>`

Comment: It's a legacy site; the program that generates the HTML was written back around 2003. The `<label>Option 1</label>` syntax is clearly preferable but I don't believe it was widely supported 10 years ago.

Comment: Just because it wasn't *fashionable* to use the label element 10 years ago doesn't mean it wasn't supported.  IE5.5 is listed as having *full support* for labels according to Sitepoint (see:  http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/label) and is the only reference I can find that specifies a version number.

Comment: Well, I don't have time to research it all now, but I do believe there were reasons back then not to use the cleaner syntax, and that it was not merely an issue of it being unfashionable. It might have had to do with the event-model, something about clicks on the label versus clicks on the input. But I agree with you in principle, K.I.S.S. -- whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not clearing your floats

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yN2E8/5/)

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

If you don't like to add an element specially to clear floats you can also use this, which I personally never use

```
.chkitemcontainer {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also if you are not bothered for old browsers, you can also self clear the parent element by using `:after` selector with display table property

Comment: It's 2013, there's no reason to suggest let alone *use* extra markup for the purpose of clearing floats.

Comment: If it was new development, I'd agree with @cimmanon. But the site is 10 years old and I have to deal with it as it is.

Comment: Accepting this answer as the answer to the specific problem, with its "givens" -> legacy markup. Thanks, Mr Allen. And thanks to the others who replied.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is a mess, try not to overdo the divs and just stick to semantic HTML, such as in http://jsfiddle.net/yN2E8/6/, then style the elements after the HTML is clean and tidy. Floats specifically should not be used for generic layout issues, they generate more problems than they solve unless specifically fit for the purpose.

### HTML

```
<label><input type="checkbox"> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Option 2</label>
```

### CSS

```
label {
    display:block;
}
```